# When using XmlReader, the HasValue property returns False! Why?

Tags: c#, xml, .net-4.0

Here is my XML file...

```
<application>
  <name>My Application</name>
  <ou/>
  <area/>
  <created time="na"/>
  <id closed="no"/>
  <description>My App Description</description>
  <version type="beta">1.0</version>
  <modified>02/24/2016</modified>
  <files>
    <file>
      <name>my_app.exe</name>
      <size type="bytes" complete="yes" updated="no">225684</size>
      <description>Main GUI for Application.</description>
      <version>1.5</version>
      <modified>02/24/2016</modified>
    </file>
    <file>
      <name>testfile.dll</name>
      <size type="bytes" complete="yes" updated="no">1024</size>
      <description>Support DLL for Application.</description>
      <version>1.1</version>
      <modified>02/23/2016</modified>
    </file>
  </files>
</application>
```

I use this to read my XML file...

```
using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create("my_xml_file.xml"))
{
  while (!reader.EOF)
  {
    switch (reader.NodeType)
    {
      case XmlNodeType.Element:
        if (reader.HasValue)
          Debug.WriteLine("Node Value:" + reader.ReadString());
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

I don't know why, but for some reason my `reader.HasValue` property is always `FALSE`.  I thought that property was supposed to be `TRUE` when there was a value on that node. If I just call `reader.ReadString()` every time, it will advance the reader and mess up what I'm trying to do.  Am I going wrong about this?

Comment: @zx485 for the record, there was no spelling errors.  :P  Seeing as how I can't spell to save my life I figured I would be proud of my accomplishment and boast about it.  ;)

Comment: Well spoken Arvo. I do respect your honest criticism. I have to admit I'm not a native speaker of the english language. Nevertheless, let me explain my primary main objective: I'm not here to chastise you or anyone else for incorrect spelling or grammar. I'm just trying to improve the readability for everyone else by removing misleading combinations of words and highlighting keywords. This is in total congruence with community standards encouraged by the SO team. Improving the readability of postings alleviates comprehension, which is beneficial to the reader (the person who may answer the q.)

Comment: 100% agree!  Are you available for my everyday grammar needs?

Comment: **No!** I'm merely available for the grammar needs of the SO community ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element does not itself have a value (in the sense you mean - it cannot) - the "text" node within the element does.

```
      case XmlNodeType.Text:
      Console.Write(reader.Value);
      break;
```

Comment: Well, I guess that makes sense...  Is there a way to tell if there is a value before calling ReadString()?

Comment: Yep - your original thought - reader.HasValue - but call it on the text node not the element (i.e. call it on the reader when you are at the text node)